# I need to clean my runspace between each loop - how do I tidy my script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works great. It is quite complex and does numerous "things".. My problem started when I put the entire 1000-line script in a while-loop..

**Some/many of my variables are doubled and messed up for each loop..**

This is of course because I run the script in the same runspace.. So, what should I do? Delete all my variables with `remove-variable` at the end of my script? Or is there some kind of magic thing that lets me clear my runspace between each run?

I feel that I've cluttered things up and that I need some kind of scanner that tells me if I have any unneeded funcions/variables.. I am still in the early phases of learning and this script has been with me "all the way", so it is by no means good coding..

So, what would be "best practice" in my situation?

Comment: Hi Bart! Why did you edit my question?

Comment: Maybe all 1000 lines don't need to be run in a loop? :-)

Comment: Best practice would be to break it up into smaller scripts and (or at a push) explicitly initialise your variables. Some sort of clear runspace manouvre would be addressing the symptom, you could have the same problem within one run.

Comment: It is a serverscan I do on all my servers so it is quite extensive and needed, yes:)

Comment: Definitely a design problem. As a short term solution you can remove variables that are causing issues at the end of each loop using `Remove-Variable -Name var1, var2, var3`. As a long term solution start analyzing what all your 1000 lines is doing and find things you can break out into re-usable functions. As a best practice you want to strive for modular, reusable code that you can quickly import into other projects rather than a monolithic chunk of code with many interdependencies which limit reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something like this to the initialization script for the job:

```
 $sysvars = get-variable | select -Expand name

  function remove-uservars {
     get-variable |
       where {$sysvars -notcontains $_.name} |
         remove-variable
    }
```

Then at the top of your while loop, dot source the remove-uservars function:

```
. remove-uservars
```

The should remove any variables your script created before each loop starts.

Comment: Fanrastic! Just what I was looking for:) But why should i dot-source the function? To affect the global scope?

Comment: You would dot-source it to affect the current scope (which might or might not be the global scope).

Answer (score 2):

If starting with a clean "scope" every time is sufficient then try this:

```
while (<loop_condition>)
{
    & {
        ... 1000 lines of script 
    }
}
```

Every time you execute the "1000 lines of script" above you'll get a new scope so variables local to that scope will need re-initializing. If your script sets global or script variables e.g. `$global:foo` or `$script:bar` then this approach might not work (depends on whether you want the global/script changes to persist between loop iterations or not).

The following (admittedly contrived example) demonstrates how creating a new scope can give you a fresh set of "local" variables each time through the loop:

```
PS> while (1) { $local += 10; Start-Sleep -milli 500; $local }
10
20
30
40
PS> while (1) { & {$local += 10; Start-Sleep -milli 500; $local} }
10
10
10
10
```

If you really need a completely fresh runspace (clean slate of global and script variables), you can start a job instead which will get you a brand spanking new runspace each time through the loop but the perf won't be as good:

```
while (<loop_condition>)
{
    $job = Start-Job { <path to 1000 line script> }
    Wait-Job $job
    Receive-Job $job
}
```